# Unable to access terminal

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, dell

I've loaded ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto my Dell XPS 1530 (Vista) laptop, but am having serious issues.  I can run ubuntu fine when testing it from the DVD, but after installation it says I must restart to complete.  Once I restart, I see nothing but the black screen and cursor.

I've poked around a fair bit and see that question has been addressed a few times, BUT every instance begins with accessing the terminal - which I'm unable to do unless I'm in demo mode from the DVD.  Once that is ejected, hitting CTRL+ALT+T or other combos does nothing.

How can I access the terminal another way?  Any tips appreciated.

-Linux newbie.

Comment: Can you change ttys? `ctrl + alt + F1`

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1–F6</kbd> into a tty.

Comment: I have tried CTRL+ALT+x during and after the startup but none gets me the terminal, only black screen with cursor.